# How corda network is designed

Tags: corda

Corda doc says

"Admission to the network
Unlike traditional blockchain, Corda networks are semi-private. To join a network, a node must obtain a certificate from the network operator. This certificate maps a well-known node identity to:"

I have a few questions about how corda netowrk is desined.

1. How network is partitioned.
   Can all corda instance form one network? Or, are there several networks that can be connected?
2. Who is network operator?
   Is it one party? Can that operator dominate network arbitrary?
3. Is Notary  included in network?
   Is Notary a component of network, or can notary notrize several corda netowrks?
   Does network operator authorize notary, or trust notary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Corda network is a set of well identified legal entities. When you want to join a network you sign a legal document (participation terms of use) and then you submit something called Certificate Signing Request; once it's approved your node automatically downloads the required certificates that identify it on that network and allows it to become discoverable by other nodes so it can interact with them.

Corda network is an example, and I recommend that you go through their website: https://corda.network

In the case of Corda network, the operator is a consortium; not one organization.

That link I shared, will answer all of your questions:

1. Participation: https://corda.network/participation/index
2. Governance: https://corda.network/governance/index
3. Types of networks in Corda network: https://corda.network/participation/network-choice
4. Notary: https://corda.network/participation/notary-considerations